# Bubble chart in R

Tags: r

all I have used this script to get this bubble plot

```
library(reader) 
data <- read.csv 
r <- c(1,194,26302,81,69, 12,11617,55,10) 
dfdata = data.frame(data,r) 
dfdata 
sizeRange <- c(5,20) 
library(ggplot2) 
ggplot(data, aes(x=0,ï..Phylum)) + 
geom_point(aes(size = r,alpha = 7,colour = "red", stroke=2)) + 
scale_size(range = sizeRange) + 
theme_minimal()+
theme(legend.position = "none")
```

I am trying to reduce the axis distance for this plot. How that can be done. And also, these bubble size is not coming properly according to the "r" values.

Please help.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Make your x-axis variable a factor or character, not a numeric

Comment: We need more of your data.  Can you use `dput(dfdata)` and paste the result in your original post?

Comment: Add `r` as a column to your data frame so it gets associated with the correct rows of data.

Comment: > dput(dfdata)
structure(list(ï..Phylum = c("Abditibacteriota", "Acidobacteria", 
"Actinobacteria", "Aquificae", "Armatimonadetes", "Atribacterota", 
"Bacteroidetes", "Balneolaeota", "Caldiserica"), Total = c(1L, 
194L, 26302L, 81L, 69L, 12L, 11617L, 55L, 10L), r = c(1, 194, 
26302, 81, 69, 12, 11617, 55, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L)

Comment: But also your range of R is intense, from 1 to over 26,000. I don't think size is a good choice for a variable that varies that much - if the bubble of size 26,000 is small enough to not take up the whole screen, the bubble of size 1 will be invisible. (So basically all your small R values show up the same small size at the lower end of your scale, and the two > 10,000 points show up at the top end of the scale, because you have nothing in the middle)

Comment: Yes, right . So, according to you which strategy will work better for such kind of data

Comment: You should [edit] the question to include your data rather than put it in a comment

Comment: With bubble charts, it often makes more sense to use `scale_size_area()` instead of the default `scale_size()`, since this will scale the total area of the bubbles to the data, instead of the radius. This will slightly help (but not resolve) the difficult challenge of representing values with very different scales.

Comment: Personally I would always use scale_size() and to refine the size of your buble is just about data transformation, sure often transforming to area is sufficient, you just transform r to πr2 to do the same, but often enough you need another transformation like log10, sqrt of your size. Either way is fine of course, point is there are more ways of transforming the scale of the bubble.